# Android studio gradle issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How can i solve this error?

> Error:BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'ijinit1_85y5oikt7gt3dvayylq0878hy' unsupported Target TYPE_PARAMETER

[image]

Comment: Its even coming when i create new project. So i think its not a issue of any xml code. See the edited image with new project. There is no layout and no java code.

Comment: See the edited image with new project. There is no layout and no java code.

Comment: find a similar problem from google, [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66853)

Comment: open module settings and check the values -compile sdk version and build tool version. **click on your app and hit f4**

Comment: Where can i found module settings ?

Comment: ok I checked. compile sdk version and build tool version is blank.

Comment: select the appropriate values and check dependencies

Comment: what about the other options ?

Comment: In dependency, its saying "nothing to show"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this by installing 64 bit windows 7 O.S. Previously, I was having 32 bit Windows 7 O.S.

Answer (score 0):

Change your module settings as shown

[image]

Comment: I did. But when i press "OK", nothing happens.

Comment: open your app's build.gradle and add `dependencies{ compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])}`

Comment: you can find build.gradle in the app folder of your application

Comment: in build.gradle file, i am having this: `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`. Should i remove it ?

Comment: bro find the build.gradle file in your app folder C:\Users\USER_NAME\AndroidStudioProjects\YOUR_APP_NAME\app\build.gradle

Comment: `dependencies{ compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])}` - this line is already there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83533/discussion-between-shekhar-chaudhary-and-bunny).